# How to validate form from <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, anchor

For my project I need to use an anchor (**< a >** -tag) to **submit** a form. Everything works fine, ***except for validation*** where I need to check if the user entered all fields and in the right format.

Here is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(){
        var x=document.forms["register"]["email"].value
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length){
          alert("Enter a valid e-mail address");
          return false;
          }

        x=document.forms["register"]["username"].value
        if (x==null || x=="")
          {
          alert("Enter full name");
          return false;
          }

        x=document.forms["register"]["gender"].value
        if (x==null || x=="")
          {
          alert("Enter your gender");
          return false;
          }
    }
</script>
```

Now this is what I want to submit

```
    <form name="register" action="after_registration.php" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    ...
    <a class="nonblock" href="javascript:document.register.submit();"><!-- content --><p id="n62">Register</p>
    </form>
```

But it doesn't work. No matter what I enter, even if the fields stay blank, the form submits anyway. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this JavaScript, I don't know where to start. I'm going to have to recommend reading ["JavaScript: The Good Parts"](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it up like this instead.

First of all, don't place javascript in the href. Leave it blank and return false from onclick handler to stop navigation. Second, call validateForm from onclick handler.

```
<a class="nonblock" href="" onclick="validateForm(); return false;" />
```

Remove onsubmit call from form

```
<form name="register" action="after_registration.php" method="get" >
```

In validateForm() submit the form instead.

```
//if no errors then
document.forms["register"].submit();
```

Comment: It's better to at least put `#` in the `href` so if `validateForm` fails with an exception you don't lose the user's form by reloading a different document.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a link, use a `<button type=submit>`

```
<button type=submit class="nonblock"><!-- content --><p id="n62">Register</p></button>
```

This doesn't require any javascript, and as long as your `form`'s `onsubmit` handler is set up right will get you what you want.

Comment: The thing is that I have to use an anchor. I know 'submit' button would be much easier, but I gotta use a link.